# Artifactory Hudson Builds not showing artifacts

Tags: jenkins, hudson, artifactory

I'm trying to setup Artifactory(free version) and Hudson to deploy artifacts.
The main stuff already works, i can deploy to Artifactory via Hudson. Using the Artifactory Hudson Plugin with generic deployment.

I am also able to browse the deployed stuff via the Tree & Simple Browser.
What not works correctly is the Build Browser, it does show everything except the artifacts deployed by the build. In the published modules view it should show all artifacts, but the tables are just greyed out for me.

Example how it should look: 
[Link to the official Jfrog Artifactory demo repository](http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/webapp/builds/jenkins-plugin-dev/854/2013-12-23T11:18:13.874+0000/org.jenkins-ci.plugins%3aartifactory:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT/?15)

Does anyone know if this view is maybe a pro feature, or any other tips how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The build integration feature is limited in the OSS version. You need the Pro version to get the full deal.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the description setter plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin . In my case i take the last revision and put a link to the artifact in artifactory. In this way on every build i can see a direct link to the artifact changing the path like you want.